# replace rows in table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have `123 456 789` and i don't know how i can replace with this values `999 888 777`.
I want to avoid an update query for each case, because i have many values to replace.

```
 table_A
 id 
 123
 456
 789
 ...
```

---

```
table_A
id
999
888
777
...
```

I need an alternative to this type of query.

```
UPDATE table_A
SET id=999
WHERE id=123
```

Comment: :On what basis you're replacing value ?any logic,otherwise there is no option other than hardcoding the values for update

Comment: @GauravSoni the logic is the index order. The position 0 should be the same in the old and new value.

Comment: How are the values related? for example, if I provide 123, will it always become 999? Is there a mathematical relationship between old and new? If I have value 333 in the old version, what will it become in the new?

Comment: no, the numbers are just a demo. If i have these values in an array, i am just concerned about the index position.

Comment: Then this isn't a MySQL question, because MySQL doesn't support arrays. If you have an array in a different table, then you can update based on values in that table.

Comment: @anvd:So according to you position 0 is having the old value ,then how come the new value populate .For eg:(index-value)0-12,1-13,In this case from what value we are going to replace 13,if it is at index 1

Comment: @JeremySmyth I know, the array is just to explain my idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using `CASE`, like this:

```
UPDATE table_A
SET id = CASE
    WHEN id = 123 THEN 999
    WHEN id = 456 THEN 888
    WHEN id = 789 THEN 777
END
```

Comment: This isn't valid MySQL syntax.

Comment: @darkajax hmm comment got lost, but yeah it was good to have some reassurance!

Answer (score 1):

you can use a case statement to do an update.

See the documentation [here.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html)